# Calling isKindOfClass: on nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, null, key

One of my methods needs to return `nil` if no value exists in an dictionary for a specific key or if the value is not of class `NSArray`.

This could be done like this:

```
if (![dict objectForKey:@"key"]) return nil;

id tmp = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
return  [tmp isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] ? tmp : nil;
```

I was wondering whether it is well defined to write this mess as:

```
if (![[dict objectForKey:@"key"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) return nil;
return [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
```

What happens here if `[dict objectForKey:@"key"]` returns `nil`?

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to test, but in objective-C you can safely send messages to `nil` - it will just return `nil` which is false. Personally, I prefer your first form, but without the unnecessary initial `if`  It only accesses the dictionary once and has a single return

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you really much! I'll go with your recommended form.